# Relative positioning in CSS is completely different in Safari and Firefox?

Tags: css, forms, radio-button, css-position

I am new to CSS and have been trying to create a web form with the radio buttons aligned next to text fields. However, in Firefox the radio boxes look fine, but when I check in Safari the radio boxes are in the middle of the text fields.

The CSS looks like this:

```
   input#answers
{
     display: block;
    height: 31px;
    left: 87px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 350px;
}

input[type="radio"]
{
    display: inline- block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 249px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and the HTML like this:

```
    <form id="quizCreator" name="quizCreator" method="post" action="quiz.maker.php">
    <label><span><img src="images/quizcreatorText.ques.png" hspace="79px" vspace="70px" class="titles"  /></span>      <br />
      <input type="text" name="question" id="question" />
    </label>
    <label><img src="images/quizcreatorText.ans.png" hspace="79px" vspace="70px" class="titles" id="ans" />      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="creator" value="myform" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="answer1" id="answers" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="radio1" />
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="text" name="answer2" id="answers" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" value="radio2" />
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="text" name="answer3" id="answers" />
  </label>  
    <label>
     <input name="radio" type="radio" class="radio" id="radio3" value="radio3" />
  </label>  

    <label>
      <input type="text" name="answer4" id="answers" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input name="radio" type="radio" id="radio4" value="radio4" />
    </label>
    <span><input  type="image" src="images/quiznameText.next.png"  name="nextPage" id="nextPage"  class="nxtbutton" /></span>
</form>
```

I've tried using relative positioning and margins, but while it fixes the problems in Safari, Firefox then looks wrong. Is there a way to make them both work as I want with a single set of code?  (And what about MSIE?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using relative positioning for this.

The proper structure is something like this (not sure if you want the text before or after):

```
<div class="answers">
<ul>
    <li><label>your text</label><input type="radio" /></li>
    ...repeat...
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.answers ul, .answers li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.answers li {
    clear:both
}

.answers label {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}

.answers input {
     display:block;
     float:left;
}
```